# VB textbox and width prob

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

hi there im trying to design a section in my program that builds layers represented by rectangles, depending on the sizes inputed will decide upon the outcome of the rectangle width. Im having a problem when entering < 0 it will revert to 1 or 0.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rectangle As Integer
    rectangle = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(rectangle)
    Form2.RectangleShape1.Width = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    If Val(TextBox1.Text) >= 1.0 Or Val(TextBox1.Text) <= 1.5 Then
        Form2.RectangleShape1.Width = 75
    End If
    If Val(TextBox1.Text) >= 1.5 Then
        Form2.RectangleShape1.Width = 120
    End If
    If Val(TextBox1.Text) <= 1.0 Then
        Form2.RectangleShape1.Width = 55
    End If
    Form2.RectangleShape1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
```

Comment: Why are you using `Val` ? Why don't you make it impossible for the user to type in letters in the textbox ?

Comment: i want to have so i can have if textbox.text <=1 or > 0.5 but it doesnt respond

Comment: Yes but you don't do anything with the symbol. This : `Val("< 0")` will return : `0` (As a double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say with the provided information and I don't understand exactly what you are doing but a few things seems wrong there.

### The *you lost me* part

Let's look at this first :

```
Dim rectangle As Integer 
rectangle = Val(TextBox1.Text)
TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(rectangle)
Form2.RectangleShape1.Width = Val(TextBox1.Text)
```

- So you declare an integer
- Take the text of some textbox and select only the numbers from it by taking out characters
- You assign back that value in the Textbox with a `ToString()` on the Integer
- You assign the value of the textbox once again taking out characters (you already did that)

You can resume this line with :

```
Form2.RectangleShape1.Width = CDbl(Val(TextBox1.Text))
```

I changed the conversion to doubles because I'm certain you want decimals. Integers can't have decimals. Without decimals, these two conditions would be **the exact same thing** :

```
If Val(TextBox1.Text) >= 1.0 Or Val(TextBox1.Text) <= 1.5 Then
    Form2.RectangleShape1.Width = 75
End If
If Val(TextBox1.Text) >= 1.5 Then
    Form2.RectangleShape1.Width = 120
End If
```

Since you can either have 1 or 2. (So checking if it's between 1 and 1.5 OR 1.5 and 2 is pointless).

### Val

You probably know this but [val](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will return the numbers in a string. So as I asked in the comments, why don't you prevent the user from inputting something else than numbers ?

Let's say **you** want to have this as result :  `"< 0"`.

- If you prevent letter and symbol he will have to input only `"0"`
- If you do it like you're doing right now he will input `"< 0"` the val function will only return `"0"` so telling me you need the `"<"` is against your current logic.

### But I want the number and the symbol...

Don't worry. If you are make sure the user will only input what you want (by putting restriction on the possible characters to input), you can catch the whole content of the textbox.

```
If myTextBox.Text = "< 1.5" Then 
'Do something cool
Else If myTextBox.Text = "< 0" Then
'Do something cooler
Else
'Do nothing
End If
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond and to write all that, I am trying to represent layers that normally would be in meters, 1m, 1.5m, 0.5m, 0,25 etc, depending on the number inserted will allocate a size for which the rectangle layer will be, more than 1.5, more than 1m but less than 1.5m or less than 1m, more than 0.5,

Comment: Well in that case don't use integers. They can't have decimals. I will write a working code for with the specified information.

Comment: yeah thats what it was, if i changed integer to double it worked no problem, brilliant thanks :)

Comment: would it be straight forward to restrict the number entered into text box to between 0-4.0?

Comment: Yes use the validating event of the textbox. Check if the value is between 0 and 4